# How to restore (mobile) data usage?

Tags: root-access, restore, mobile-data, nandroid

I've an S3 and until yesterday I've PACMAN ROM running - previous: Paranoid Android

I made a Nandroid backup, in using titanium backup but I've forgotten to save my mobile data usage.

**Now I'm searching for an way to get it back (without restore the backup, if possible)
Is there any absolute path to a file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time the correct approach, hopefully:

[XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2462525) mentions the stats being located in `/data/system/netstats/*` (the statistic data you are looking for) and `/data/system/netpolicy.xml` (configuration of the applications that have restricted reference data).

Comment: thx - yes that looks good... - extracted the files - note only merging is missing.. :D

Comment: I wouldn't expect a merge functionality here. Those data are not intended to be dealt with this way :) So if my answer solved your issue, it would be nice if you could "accept" it (by hitting the check-mark next to it) – so it shows up as "solved". Thanks, and enjoy!